# NHibernate Select Parent Fields Only

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I have a parent entity A that has many B children.

To increase my website's performance, I'd like to first select the parent A by a given ID and show that to the user. And in the background load A's children and display those when ready.

My current query :

```
var result = session.QueryOver<A>().Where(a.ID = "123").List<A>();
return result.FirstOrDefault();
```

This query selects and returns A and all of his children.

Anyone has any idea how I could make nhibernate load only A's fields?

Using lazy is not good for me since I want to create another query that selects the children after the user received A.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a DTO class that exactly describes what fields from `A` you want:

```
public class ADto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then use QueryOver to select just those properties:

```
ADto result = null;

ADto dto = session.QueryOver<A>()
    .Where(a => a.Id == "123")
    .SelectList(list => list
        .Select(a => a.Id).WithAlias(() => result.Id)
        .Select(a => a.Property1).WithAlias(() => result.Property1)
        .Select(a => a.Property2).WithAlias(() => result.Property2)
    )
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBeanTransformer<ADto>())
    .SingleOrDefault<ADto>();
```

Then write a separate, similar query for retrieving `A`'s children.